# unable to connect to SharePoint using python error: list index out of range?

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have python code to connect to sharepoint and download files to dbfs.

The code was working fine till yesterday, but as of today I am getting 'List Index out of range Error'

The error occurs while retrieving the authentication token from sharepoint.

Below is the code that was working fine till today

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
`ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url_shrpt)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username_shrpt, password_shrpt):
  ctx = ClientContext(url_shrpt, ctx_auth)
```

Comment: Got to know that MFA has implemented  on the service account which is used to connect to sharepoint .

Comment: Don't use comments for adding to a question. Just [edit] the question and make your changes and additions. I think you ought to show any errors you are getting, and reformat the text so it is normal text.

Comment: No need for bold type for the entire text of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I first tried.

The problem I had was that my credentials were not correct.

Double check your username and password

Answer (score 0):

The credentials are correct ,we have a code in place to download from sharepoint using the same account and it is working fine.We are using basic authentication to connect to outlook

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer, it should be a comment instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33803789)